# How TestNG handles duplicate priority of test methods in sub class?

Tags: testng

I have created inherited testng classes with duplicate priorities in super and sub class as below:

```
package PriorityExamples;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

class SuperTestNGClass1
{

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void apple()
    {
        System.out.println("apple");
    }


    @Test(priority=2)
    public void cat()
    {
        System.out.println("cat");
    }
}

public class DuplicatePriority extends SuperTestNGClass1{


    @Test(priority=1)
    public void disp()
    {
        System.out.println("disp");
    }


    @Test(priority=2)
    public void ball()
    {
        System.out.println("ball");
    }




}
```

And testng.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test" >
    <classes>
      <class name="PriorityExamples.DuplicatePriority"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When I run , i get output as below:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
disp
apple
ball
cat

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

I understand that if there is tie between priority, based on dictionary order, method will be executed. So I was expecting "apple" should have run before "disp". I am not getting logic how priority will be decided in case of inheritance?